# Why can't I use iframe document like $(document)

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe, document

`console.log($(document));` gives me:

```
▼k.fn.init [document]
►0: document
length: 1
►__proto__: Object(0)
```

at best trying to select an iframe document gives me:

```
▼k.fn.init []
►__proto__: Object(0)
```

using my function refuses to work with the iframe ouput

how do I get the same output as document for my iframe?

iframevar.contents() gives:

```
▼k.fn.init [document, prevObject: k.fn.init(1)]
►0: document
length: 1
►prevObject: k.fn.init [iframe#contframe.contframe]
►__proto__: Object(0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. Do you just want to access `iframe` element?

Comment: when I do it doesn't function the same as accessing $(document),
all other attempts give undefined

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
varname = iframevar.contents();

delete varname.prevObject;
```